# Two questions about the definition of torsion of a curve

Tags: differential-geometry, vectors, definition, inner-products

The following is from the Wikipedia [article](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Torsion_of_a_curve#Definition) on the torsion of a curve:

[The torsion] is found from the equation

$$B'=-\tau N$$

which means

$$\tau =- N \cdot B'$$

---

Here $N$ is the normal unit vector, and $B$ the binormal unit vector.

---

$Q_1$: considering that the torsion $\tau$ is a scalar, the first equation implies that $B'$ is parallel to $N$. Why is this the case?

$Q_2$: how does the first equation imply the second?

Comment: There’s a proof here you can try to read: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Frenet-Serret_formulas. The second equation follows by taking dot product with $-N$ in the first, and using that $N\cdot N=1$.

Comment: You can sort of ask yourself: how can $B$ turn? It can’t change length, so $B’$ is perpendicular to $B$. And loosely, if it were to turn in the direction of $T$, then $N$ would be at a wrong place, breaking the setup. So it must turn only in the direction of $N$.

Comment: For the second equation, you can also just remember that the dot product of parallel vector is the (signed) product of their lengths.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I feel like this should be a duplicate, but I couldn't find an answer that clearly proves that $B'$ is parallel to $N$. The wikipedia proof also doesn't really go into this. So here goes, with all the details:

We have
$$
B' = (T\times N)' = T'\times N + T\times N'.
$$
The first term gives
$$
T'\times N = \kappa N\times N = 0
$$
(where $\kappa$ is the curvature, though that is irrelevant for us). What about $N'$? We will write $N'$ as a linear combination of $T$, $N$ and $B$.  Since $N$ is of constant length, $N'$ has no component in the $N$ direction. (Proof: $N'\cdot N = \frac12(N\cdot N)' = \frac12(1)'=0$.) So we have $N'=\alpha T + \beta B$ for some scalars $\alpha$ and $\beta$. But then
$$
B' = T\times N' = \alpha T\times T + \beta T\times B = -\beta N.
$$
And we define $\tau=\beta$. Incidentally, $\alpha=-\kappa$, which follows by calculating $(T\cdot N)'$.

---

**Alternatively:** Write $B' = \alpha T + \beta N + \gamma B$. We have
$$
0 = (B\cdot T)' = B'\cdot T + B\cdot T' = B'\cdot T + B\cdot (\kappa N) = B'\cdot T 
\implies \alpha = 0,
$$
and
$$
0 = (B\cdot B)' = 2B'\cdot B \implies \gamma = 0.
$$
So
$$
B' = \beta N,
$$
and we define $\tau = -\beta$.

---

Oh, I forgot your second question, which I answered in the comment:
$$
B' = -\tau N \implies B'\cdot N = -\tau N \cdot N = -\tau.
$$